# Order of rows changes when creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've a weird issue.

```
    DROP table IF EXISTS ipl;
    CREATE TABLE ipl(
    match_id VARCHAR(50),
    batting VARCHAR(50),
    bowling VARCHAR(50),
    overn VARCHAR(50),
    batsman VARCHAR(50),
    bowler VARCHAR(50),
    super_over VARCHAR(50),
    bat_runs VARCHAR(50),
    extra_runs VARCHAR(50),
    total_runs VARCHAR(50),
    player_out VARCHAR(50),
    how VARCHAR(50),
    fielder VARCHAR(50));
    BULK INSERT ipl 
        FROM 'F:\Study\Semesters\4th 
            Sem\COL362\HomeWork\1\Dataset\deliveries.csv' 
        WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR= ',');
    SELECT * FROM ipl;
```

This is the code I'm using to make the table in SSMS. match_id goes from 1 to about 290, in increasing order in the csv file. When I executed this query once, everything was ok. But, when I did that again, some rows from the middle were moved to the last.

You can see that below:
(Note that jump from 4 to 49)

[image]

I don't know what's wrong. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: A relational database table is logically and unordered set of rows. If you need a particular sequence, specify an `ORDER BY` clause when selecting from the table.

Comment: @DanGuzman oh yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want rows in a particular order, you need an `order by`.  How can you do this with a `bulk insert`?  Well, you need an identity column.  The idea is to create the table with an identity and use a view for the bulk insert:

```
create table ipl (
    ipl_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);

create view vw_ipl as 
    select match_id, batting, bowling, . . .
    from ipl

bulk insert vw_ipl 
    from 'F:\Study\Semesters\4th Sem\COL362\HomeWork\1\Dataset\deliveries.csv' 
    with (fieldterminator= ',' );

select *
from ipl
order by ipl_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a relational database SQL server do not guarantee a particular order of returned data. If you need ordered data, specify order by clause.